# Excel doesnt want to show text as text

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column which I defined as text.
Everything is shown as expected except one value: `182E00301` for some reason excel convert it to `1.82E+303` I understand that sometimes it recognize text as numbers but I defined the column as text not as scientific. What can I do?

Comment: Format Text before writing the Value, if you write it before Formatting Excel will recognize it as Scientific and even if you format it later to Text it will not change

Comment: @yass you can post that as an answer

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce that behaviour. For me, the value shows as expected, even when the cell format is "General".

To force a text display, you can edit the cell and prepend the value with a single quote (or apostrophe).

Depending on your Excel version there may be other ways to deal with the data, for example, in Excel 2010 and later you could use Power Query to load, clean and format the data before displaying it in the sheet. That will give you more control and you won't be exposed to Excel's defaults getting things wrong.

Comment: I successfully reproduce the problem in Microsoft Office 2016 with General formatting. Changing format to Text eliminates the problem.

Comment: @AdiNugroho What build? I'm on Insider Fast 1704 build 8027.1000. Maybe the behaviour got fixed.

Comment: I'm not aware of Office Insider build, but I'm on Office 2016 version 1702 build 7870.2031, and I'm not an Office Insider.

Answer (score 1):

If you write the Value **182E00301** before Formatting the Cell as Text, Excel will recognize it as `Scientific` numbers with **E** and not Text,that is why it become in Excel **1.82E+303** even if you change the Format later to Text (after writing it) it will stay the same.

The solution is to `Format Cells` as `Text` before writing the value **182E00301**
In that case Excel will recognize it as Text and it will show as needed.